# Trying to create readable output bundle but error message:- Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/index.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-core, npm, webpack

I am using Webpack version 6.14.8 in an Asp.net Core Razor Pages application in Visual Studio 2019. I am trying to create a readable output file. Here is the structure:-

```
|-->wwwroot
 ----->src (created manually)
 ------->index.js (created manually)
|-->dist (generated by webpack)
 ------->main.js (webpack bundle)
|-->node_modules (npm init webpack --save-dev)
|-->package.json  (npm init -y)
 ----->package-lock.json (npm init -y)
|-->webpack.config.js (manually configured)
```

The src/index.js file is blank index.js file.

The package.json: -

```
{
  "name": "aspnet.core",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "", 
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "wbp": "webpack --entry ./src/index.js --output ./dist/main.js --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "startbootstrap-simple-sidebar": "^5.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.1.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.0.0"
  }
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/path/to/your/file.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
};
```

I am trying to create a readable output folder: -"dist/main.js" in wwwroot folder: dist/main.js. However, when I ran the command: npm run wbp, I received the following error message about the entry module could not be found: Error: Can't resolve './src/index.js' in C:\ directory folder: -

```
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\My Folder\Visual Studio\Projects\Final\HelloWorld >npm run wbp

>helloword@1.0.0 wbp C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\My Folder\Visual Studio\Projects\Final\HelloWorld 
>webpack ./src/index.js --output ./dist/main.js --mode development

asset main.js 1.47 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
.dist/main.js 644 bytes built] code generated

ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/index.js' in C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\My Folder\Visual Studio\Projects\Final\HelloWorld 

webpack 5.1.3 compiled with 1 error in 858 ms

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! HelloWorld@1.0.0 build: `webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the HelloWorld@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-18T07_19_13_940Z-debug.log

C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\My Folder\Visual Studio\Projects\Final\HelloWorld >
```

The dist/main file was created in the project directory and its contents are: -

```
/*
 * ATTENTION: The "eval" devtool has been used (maybe by default in mode: "development").
 * This devtool is not neither made for production nor for readable output files.
 * It uses "eval()" calls to create a separate source file in the browser devtools.
 * If you are trying to read the output file, select a different devtool (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)
 * or disable the default devtool with "devtool: false".
 * If you are looking for production-ready output files, see mode: "production" (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/).
 */
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/*!**********************!*\
  !*** ./dist/main.js ***!
  \**********************/
/*! unknown exports (runtime-defined) */
/*! runtime requirements:  */
eval("/*\n * ATTENTION: The \"eval\" devtool has been used (maybe by default in mode: \"development\").\n * This devtool is not neither made for production nor for readable output files.\n * It uses \"eval()\" calls to create a separate source file in the browser devtools.\n * If you are trying to read the output file, select a different devtool (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)\n * or disable the default devtool with \"devtool: false\".\n * If you are looking for production-ready output files, see mode: \"production\" (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/).\n */\n/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap\n/******/ \t\"use strict\";\n/******/ })()\n;\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack://HelloWorld/./dist/main.js?");
/******/ })()
;
```

I looked at the url address:- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/, and I tried the "output.path" option: [Output|webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpath), but it did not work, when I ran the "npm run wbp" command.
How do I fix the issue of input: .src/index.js file is not found and how do I create a readable output: dist/main file?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Current structure:-

```
|-->wwwroot
 ----->src (created manually)
 ------->index.js (created manually)
 ----->dist (generated by webpack-created by the command: npm run build)
 ------->main.js (webpack bundle-created by the command: npm run build)
 ------->index.html (created by the command: npm run build)
|-->node_modules (npm init webpack --save-dev)
|-->package.json  (npm init -y)
 ----->package-lock.json (npm init -y)
|-->webpack.config.js (manually configured)
```

package.json

```
  "name": "aspnet.core",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "SET NODE_ENV='production' && webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "startbootstrap-simple-sidebar": "^5.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.1.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.3.2",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.3.1"
  }
}
```

I updated the input and output files of the webpack.config.js file in development mode as follows: -

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './wwwroot/src/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist'),
        filename: 'main.js'
    },  
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(js)$/, use: { loader: 'babel-loader', options: {presets: ['@babel/preset-react']} }},
            { test: /\.(sass|scsss|css)$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
            { test: /\.(svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf)$/, use: ['file-loader'] },
        ]
    },    
    target: 'node',  // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
    externals: [nodeExternals()], //in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(), 
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),       
    ],
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development'
}
```

and afterwards run the command:- npm run build